# Issue setting up server side for MERN project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

So I'm working on my first MERN project and I am having trouble setting up the server side. I am following this tutorial https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial and trying to connect my React project to MongoDB Atlas. I have three files: server.js, conn.js, and jobs.js.

server.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config.env" });
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(require("./routes/jobs"));
// get driver connection
const dbo = require("./db/conn");

app.listen(port, () => {
  // perform a database connection when server starts
  dbo.connectToServer(function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
  });
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

conn.js:

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const Db = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
const client = new MongoClient(Db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

var _db;

module.exports = {
  connectToServer: function (callback) {
    console.log("connectToServer called");
    client.connect(function (err, db) {
      console.log("client.connect() called");
      // Verify we got a good "db" object
      if (db) {
        _db = db.db("jobs");
        console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");
      }
      return callback(err);
    });
  },

  getDb: function () {
    return _db;
  },
};
```

jobs.js:

```js
const express = require("express");

// recordRoutes is an instance of the express router.
// We use it to define our routes.
// The router will be added as a middleware and will take control of requests starting with path /record.
const recordRoutes = express.Router();

// This will help us connect to the database
const dbo = require("../db/conn");

// This help convert the id from string to ObjectId for the _id.
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;

// This section will help you get a list of all the records.
recordRoutes.route("/record").get(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("jobs");
  db_connect
    .collection("jobs")
    .find({})
    .toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(result);
    });
});

// This section will help you get a single record by id
recordRoutes.route("/record/:id").get(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
  let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) };
  db_connect.collection("jobs").findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(result);
  });
});

// This section will help you create a new record.
recordRoutes.route("/record/add").post(function (req, response) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
  let myobj = {
    name: req.body.name,
    position: req.body.position,
    level: req.body.level,
  };
  db_connect.collection("jobs").insertOne(myobj, function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    response.json(res);
  });
});

// This section will help you update a record by id.
recordRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function (req, response) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
  let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) };
  let newvalues = {
    $set: {
      name: req.body.name,
      position: req.body.position,
      level: req.body.level,
    },
  };
  db_connect
    .collection("jobs")
    .updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document updated");
      response.json(res);
    });
});

// This section will help you delete a record
recordRoutes.route("/:id").delete((req, response) => {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
  let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) };
  db_connect.collection("jobs").deleteOne(myquery, function (err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document deleted");
    response.json(obj);
  });
});

module.exports = recordRoutes;
```

When I run `node server.js`, `"connectToServer called"` gets printed out while `"client.connect() called"` doesn't. How do I fix this issue?

I'm expecting `client.connect()` to be called but it isn't printing out. This leads me to believe that my client is not connecting.

Comment: The `connect()` method doesn't accept a callback, it returns a promise. You're probably following an out-of-date tutorial

Comment: So callbacks are used in jobs.js, how do I change them so they accept promises instead of callbacks?